# Forcing token refresh but the token still has expired?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);
const setAppCookie = () => firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true).then(token => {
    Cookies.set('token', token, {
        domain: window.location.hostname,
        expire: 1 / 24,
        path: '/',
        secure: true
    });
});
const unsetAppCookie = () => Cookies.remove('token', {
    domain: window.location.hostname,
    path: '/',
});
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function ($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
}]);
app.controller("ctrlHead", ["$scope", "Auth", "$window", function ($scope, Auth, $window) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            setAppCookie();
            localStorage.setItem("authenticated", JSON.stringify("yay!"));
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("authenticated", JSON.stringify(null));
        }
    });
    $scope.authenticated = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticated"));
}]);
```

Here is my code which sets the token once I login with Firebase ^

Here is the code that checks for the token on the server:

```
router.get('/page', function(req, res, next) {
    global.page_name = current;

    const { token } = req.cookies;

    if (!token || token == undefined) {
            global.page_name = "...";

            res.redirect("/");
    }
    else {
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
        .then(decodedToken => {
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
                global.page_name = "...";

                res.redirect("/");
        });
    }  
});
```

Although I set the token to be force refreshed, I am unable to login and always get the following error:

{ Error: Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh token from your client app and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

What is going on ? What have I done wrong ?

Comment: For some reason it seems to work locally. But not in prod. It's extremely strange since it was working in prod yesterday. I must have changed something somewhere somehow :/

Comment: Perhaps a cached token? ID tokens expire after 60 seconds.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka That was it.

Comment: @TheProgrammer how did you solve the problem? I'm facing same issue.